# Zendesk Api problem with custom fields values

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api

Good morning,

I need help, I recently found the Tanabee project on github where using APPS Scripts and google sheets and the zendesk api you could extract the necessary info.

I'm looking at the documentation but I can't figure out how to extract the custom fields values.

I get a cell value of "unidentified", could you advise me ?

Attached is the code:

```html
var response = apiRequestToZendesk('tickets.json', '?sort_by=created_at&sort_order=desc&page=' + page),
fetchedTickets = response.tickets
.map(function (ticket) {
return [
ticket.id,
ticket.brand_id,
ticket.subject,
ticket.description.substring(0, 50000),//Limitamos a 50000 caracteres para evitar crash de spreadsheet
ticket.tags.join(','),
toDate(ticket.created_at),
toDate(ticket.updated_at),
/*                
ticket.custom_fields_6515116803345
ticket.custom_fields_4419313475857   
 */
ticket.custom_fields
];
}),
```

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
ticket.custom_fields_6515116803345
```

with

```
ticket.custom_fields[ticket.custom_fields.findIndex((cf) => cf.id==6515116803345)].value,
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but APPS SCRIPTS don't accept this line of code https://imgur.com/a/5PGJLdx